# Using spfun with two identically ordered sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I got two sparse matrices A and B, which have identical sparsity pattern (all nonzeros are at exactly the same locations):

```
i = randi(1000,[50,1]);
j = randi(1000,[50,1]);
a = rand(50,1);
b = rand(50,1);

A = sparse(i,j,a,1000,1000);
B = sparse(i,j,b,1000,1000);
```

I would like to calculate efficiently exp(A-B) only for the nonzeros, and save it back into A.
I tried to use spfun for that task:

```
f = @(x,y) exp(x-y);
A = spfun(f,A,B);
```

but I got an error in spfun saying: "Too many input arguments."
Can anyone suggest an efficient way to calculate it?
It should be calculated many times.

Thanks!

Edit: mikkola suggested `A = spfun(@f,A-B)` which solves the problem, but the question remains how to do it with a function of two variables that can't be solved using the same trick. For example:

```
g = @(x,y) x.*cos(y);
A = spfun(@g,A,B);
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html), I suppose you should do `spfun(@exp, A-B)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use

```
A = spfun(@exp, A-B);
```

because for entries where `A` an `B` are equal you will get `0` instead of `1`.

To solve that, you can compute the vector of exponentials at the nonzero components, and then build a sparse matrix from that:

```
A = sparse(i,j,exp(nonzeros(A)-nonzeros(B))); %// if you have i, j stored
```

or

```
A(find(A)) = exp(nonzeros(A)-nonzeros(B));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

According to the documentation, `spfun` can take only two inputs: a function and *one* sparse matrix.

So you cannot do directly what you want to do. The best solution is probably what has been suggested in the comments, *i.e.*:

```
res = spfun(@exp, A-B);
```

Best,

Comment: Sorry for this wrong answer. I just edited my answer.